# Serverless AWS Lambda : no module named `secret_manager`

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

Installed serverless-python-requirements using npm.

I use secret-manager library in handler.py

I am able to successfully deploy lambda function using serverless (no errors).

I have secret-manager listed (along with other pypi packages) in `requirements.txt`

In order to package it, I include following lines in `serverless.yml`

```
pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
```

To verify if secret-manager is packaged with the other PyPi binaries:

I downloaded the deployed lambda as a zip file and verified it does have secretmanager along with other pypi binaries.

But, still for some reason, it still fails saying secret-manager module not found..

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'secret_manager'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Note the name of folder of PyPi is `secretmanager` and the name of file inside it is `secret_manager.py`

For reference : [image: secret_manager in AWS Lambda serverless deployment]

Comment: I've never used that library in my life but according to your screenshot you should use `from secretmanager import secret_manager` or something like that

Comment: Echoing @yorodm - if you don't have the module imported in your main function handler (app.py or whatever, wherever you reference it in your code), you would receive the error you noted as it appears un-imported somewhere. You have proved it exists in the proper location though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include a separate user-written file secret_manager.py that had the logic for getting secret from secret-manager. It had nothing to do with the PyPi binary.